# How are CLR GC heaps mapped to native heaps?

Tags: memory, garbage-collection, clr, heap-memory, windbg

For example, if I see that some of those heaps are pretty big, my next question would be who (native or managed code) uses them.
How can I figure out which native heaps (!heap -s) CLR uses for its purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CLR uses VirtualAlloc to allocate memory segments to be used as the managed heaps.  You can inspect the segments using !sos.eeheap -gc.  !sos.dumpheap -stat will show you how much memory the managed heaps are using, and what types of objects are consuming memory.

Answer (score 0):

The CLR don't use any of the native heaps.
Use the SOS and !DumpHeap to see the managed heaps.

Here is [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2012/04/26/troubleshooting-memory-leaks-with-just-a-dump.aspx) for finding who is using the native heaps.

I have had some good results with [DebugDiag 1.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff420662.aspx) for finding who is using which native heap.

Edit:
Although **VirtualAlloc** is used to allocate the memory for the native heap, the !CLRUsage  reveals that there is also a native heap used. However I don’t know the purpose.

```
0:000> !CLRUsage
Native Heap for mscorwks: 0x07e60000
Number of GC Heaps: 1
------------------------------
GC Heap Size  0xbc7dd4(12,352,980)
Total Commit Size  00e22000 (14 MB)
Total Reserved Size  0225e000 (34 MB)
Initial reservation type: All at once
Initial Allocation Size: 2000000 (33,554,432) (32 MB)
Reserved Memory Size: 3000000 (50,331,648) (48 MB)
Reserved Memory Limit Size: 3000000 (50,331,648) (48 MB)
```